# Handling keypress always gives one key less as event.target.value

Tags: preact

So I was trying out preact and I need to handle keypress event to update the state and later post the values

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-9">
    <input class="" type="text" id="name" value={this.state.filled_values.name} onKeyPress={this.setValue("name")} placeholder="Your name" style="width:85%;"/>
</div>
```

And I handle this using the setValue function

```
setValue(field_name){
    return function(event){
        console.log(event.target.value)

        this.state.filled_values[field_name] = event.target.value;
        this.setState({});
        this.saveStateDebounced()
    }.bind(this)

}
```

When I type something, however, the value returned is always one key short of what I enter

eg: if I type abcd,

the last event provides "abc" as event.target.value instead of abcd

Answer (score 2):

That's the way the DOM works. The `keypress` event has been [marked as deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress) for a while. The `keyup` or `input` event are much more reliable across browsers.